# Android Layout allignment of Textview and checkbox

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, gridview

I am trying to show a textbox and checkbox in a row. But are not seems to be alligned. Also the elements of gridview are not alligned .

[image: My view in Android mobile]

My code is as following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and the code of gridview_row.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewL"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to allign textview and checkbox in a row. Also the elements of gridview must be alligned . Please help me in this regards .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

IN TWO WAYS

Give `android:gravity="center_vertical"` for both `TextView` and `CheckBox`

then `LinearLayout` height as fixed like `40dp`

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewL"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

then the second

NO need to give fixed

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewL"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="right" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

For your `GridView` **allignment**

use `android:singleLine="true"`

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Comment: I have accepted your answer as It was complete. I think others will understand.

Answer (score 0):

use `android:gravity="center_vertical"` in your textView

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00868B" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewL"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way and let me know still you have any problem
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/lnrmain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right">
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```